# Calling Methods (Java)

Tags: java, methods

Summary, I am to write a class called BankAccount and my professor has provided me with a driver.

Here is my class so far:

```
import  java.util.Date;

public class BankAccount implements AccountInterface
{
private double balance;
private String name;
private Date creationDate = new Date ();
private boolean frozen;
private double limit;
private final double MAXLIMIT = 500;
private int accountNumber;
private static int howMany;

public BankAccount( )
{
    this.name = "Classified";
    this.creationDate.getTime();
    this.frozen = false;
    this.limit = 300;
    this.howMany++;
    this.accountNumber = howMany;
    this.balance = 0;
}

public BankAccount (String creationName)
{
    this.name = creationName;
    this.creationDate.getTime();
    this.frozen = false;
    this.limit = 300;
    this.howMany++;
    this.accountNumber = howMany;
    this.balance = 0;
}

public static int getNumAccounts ( )
{
    return howMany;
}

public void deposit(double theMoney)
{
    if (frozen = true)
        throw new IllegalStateException ("Cannot Deposit - Account Is Frozen");
    else if (theMoney < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient funds");
    else
        balance = balance + theMoney;
}

public double withdraw(double theMoney)
{
    if (theMoney < 0 ||  balance == 0 || theMoney > limit || theMoney % 20 !=0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("There was an error in your withdraw.");
    else if (frozen = true)
        throw new IllegalStateException ("Cannot Deposit - Account Is Frozen");
    else
        balance = balance - theMoney;

    return balance;
}

public double getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}

public void freeze()
{
    frozen = true;
}

public void unfreeze()
{
    frozen = false;
}

public void setLimit(double newLimit)
{
    if (newLimit < 0 || newLimit > MAXLIMIT)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("There was a limit error.");
    else if (frozen = true)
        throw new IllegalStateException ("Cannot Deposit - Account Is Frozen");
    else
        limit = newLimit;
}

public double getLimit( )
{
    return limit;
}

 public String toString( )
 {
     return "\nAccount number: " + accountNumber + "\nName: " + name + "\nCreation Date: " + creationDate + "\nBalance: " + balance + "\nWithdrawal Limit: " + limit ;
 }
}
```

The problem that I am running into is when the driver calls `myAccount.unfreeze();` in my class it does not set the account to unfreeze. So When the driver goes to deposit any money my class returns `Cannot Deposit - Account Is Frozen` even though I have a method called unfreeze. I thought at first I might have missed spelled frozen or unfreeze wrong, but that is not the case. Hopefully, some fresh pair of eyes can spot something that I am skipping over.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you think `frozen = true` does? Why do you think so? What does `=` do? What does `==` do? (Voting to close as typo.)

Answer (score 2):

When you use single equation sign, you are assigning the value. Use double equal sign to check for equality. In your case you should be using `if(frozen==false)` and `if(frozen==true)` whenever you are checking for its value.

Comment: Or even more elegant, if(frozen) and if(!frozen)

Comment: Yes. Since he doesn't understand the difference between the single equal and double equal sign, had to explain him that.